# How do I use translate from a VBA macro question

Tags: vba, ms-word

Want to "batch" translate many word documents.

Tried to batch convert to docx and need to add translation.

Please see the code I am using below.

I don't know how to invoke the translation on the ActiveDocument.

```
'''VBA
    Sub ConvertDocToDocx()
    'Updated by ExtendOffice 20181128
        Dim xDlg As FileDialog
        Dim xFolder As Variant
        Dim xFileName As String
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set xDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If xDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
        xFolder = xDlg.SelectedItems(1) + "\"
        xFileName = Dir(xFolder & "*.doc", vbNormal)
        While xFileName <> ""
            Documents.Open FileName:=xFolder & xFileName, _
                ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
                PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
                WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:= _
                wdOpenFormatAuto, XMLTransform:=""

    'pseudo code ActiveDocument.MStranslateFromTo('EN','DA') 

            ActiveDocument.SaveAs xFolder & Replace(xFileName, "doc", "docx"), wdFormatDocumentDefault
            ActiveDocument.Close
            xFileName = Dir()
        Wend
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
'''
```

(code found here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/5601-word-batch-convert-doc-to-docx.html#a1 )

Comment: "Translate" means rewriting text in a different language. I believe you mean "convert", which, in this context means save one or more files in a different file format.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - I think they really mean "translate"...

Comment: @Tim Williams - You may be correct, I assumed `ActiveDocument.SaveAs xFolder & Replace(xFileName, "doc", "docx"), wdFormatDocumentDefault` and the link provided at the bottom of the post meant OP was looking to convert the files.

Comment: thanks - i talk about translate to an other language. (the code to convert format, to docx works nicely.) - I was expecting that I could invoke the translation in the same process. But I can not find any VBA examples for that. (I found some Azure base examples, but don't see the real need for going "outside" what can already be done in word).

Comment: I wonder if this could be done using a macro - that is I could simply record a macro that run the translation - and then call that macro while processing the doc/docx conversion? (this editor sucks!) Though I don't know if a macro can be called from VBA code or visa versa...

Comment: (anyway How do we format a **proper** comment for these issues ...- the above is close to unreadable  ? )  - apparently you need to add an "answer" to get the edit option...

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer**

This could be done, but the record macro do not produce the result wanted. When running this the only code made is the part where I select the code, the part where I press translate etc. is not recorded - this looks like this:

````
Sub Makro1()
'
' Makro1 Makro
'
'
    Selection.WholeStory
End Sub
```
````